# How to pause slick slider while playing viemo autolay video

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, slider, slick.js

I created slick.js slider, in that sliders I used 2 iframe viemo videos with auoplay mode and 2 images, what i am trying is how to pause the current slider while playing iframe vimeo autoplay video, after completed video the slider has to change

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.slick_slider').slick({
        dots: false,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 2000,
        autoplay: true,
        arrows: false
    });

});

 var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
    var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.9/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
<script src="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slick_slider">


            <div class="vimeo-wrapper">
                <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/565964510?api=1&byline=0&portrait=0&title=0&background=1&muted=0&autoplay=1&id=565964510" allow=autoplay  frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>

        <div>
            <img src="assets/img/img-0.jpg" class="entity-img" alt="Image"/>
        </div>

            <div class="vimeo-wrapper">
                <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/565972134?api=1&byline=0&portrait=0&title=0&background=1&muted=0&autoplay=1&id=565972134" allow=autoplay frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>

        <div>
            <img src="assets/img/img-6.jpg" class="entity-img" alt="Image"/>
        </div>

            <div class="vimeo-wrapper">
                <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/575808908?api=1&byline=0&portrait=0&title=0&background=1&muted=0&autoplay=1&id=575808908" allow=autoplay frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>

        <div>
            <img src="assets/img/img-1.jpg" class="entity-img" alt="Image"/>
        </div>


    </div>
```

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: I think you don't understand what i am trying to saying, I created 4 sliders  2 sliders videos and 2 sliders images, now what I am trying is how to pause the slider while playing the video, I don't know how to do @Andreas

Comment: In other words: _What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?_ ([What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) , [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users))

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code. This will make the slick slider pause/stop from autoplaying when the video of a current slide is playing.

Suggestion: We will use the Vimeo ID as a selector to easily target the iframe that contains the video currently playing.
So I think adding the Vimeo ID as a new iframe attribute is better.

```
<iframe data-vimeo-id="565964510" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/565964510?api=1&byline=0&portrait=0&title=0&background=1&muted=0&autoplay=1&id=565964510" allow=autoplay  frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>


$(".slick_slider").on("beforeChange", function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
if ($(this).find(".vimeo-wrapper").eq(currentSlide).find("iframe").length !== 0) {
    var vimeo_id = $(this).find(".vimeo-wrapper").eq(currentSlide).find("iframe").data("vimeo-id");

    var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe[data-vimeo-id="' + vimeo_id + '"]');
    var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);

    player.on("pause", function () {
        console.log("paused the video!");
        $(".slider-for4").slick("slickPlay");
    });

    player.on("play", function () {
        console.log("played the video!");
        $(".slider-for4").slick("slickPause");
    });
}
});
```

Hope that helps! :)